# How to concatenate zeros to a number?

Tags: javascript, concatenation

This is the number:

```
555
```

I want to make it:

```
555000
```

How to do that?

This didn't work:

```
"" + 555 + 000
```

Comment: Do some maths: `555*1000` = `555000`

Comment: What if `001` to add?

Comment: Then `555*1000+1`

Comment: If you want to do it literally by concatenating then you could do `555+"001"` but the end result will be a _string_, not a number. So if you then wanted to do further numeric calculations afterwards you'd have to parse it as a number again

Comment: Just make it a string and concatenate them. You can convert it back to a number if needed.

Comment: If you don't want to use multiplication, you can do type conversion such as parseInt(myNumber.toString() + "000");

Comment: Do you want the result to be a string or a number?

Comment: number I want to have

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
let x = Number(555 + '000')
```

Try yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Make it to string then to number :

```
let x = 555;
x +='000'
let y = Number(x)
```

Or just do the math

```
let x=555*1000
```

Comment: I know ;-) I'm writing on my phone so it's auto capitalization.

Answer (score 2):

It's 2019 :)

```js
console.log(`${555}000`);
```

Though I really encourage not to mix types.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a string and parse to a number:

```js
var n = +`${555}000`;

console.log(n);
```